Terminology for two stochastic processes admitting similar PDFs
I'm doing some work analysing some price data, and I can't quite find the correct terminology to use.
If we have a continuous time stochastic process, $X_t$, which is nearly a Brownian motion, but with some coloured noise, and we wish to say that $\exp(X_t)$ admits a PDF which is similar (in the least-squares sense) to a PDF of a uncorrelated geometric Brownian motion, $Y_t$, with some other coloured noise, is it valid to refer to these as related in a 'weak' sense?
Similarly, if $|\exp(X_t) - Y_t| < \epsilon$ , $\forall t$, can we say $X_t$ and $Y_t$ are related in any related 'strong' sense?
I apologise if this is too vague, I am finding it difficult to search the literature with out finding unrelated concepts.
